# Could we have chain style setters in C++/Java just like jquery?

Tags: java, c++, setter

I'm using C++ and Java for a while and recently I'm on jquery. I noticed jquery's chain style functions. Then I think, if we could change setters in C++/Java just like jquery? For example, if our code is

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public Person setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public Person setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then we could write code as following instead:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setName("Tom").setAge(20);
```

If we have lots of setters, this seems to be more simple.

I wonder if this is a good idea? Do you agree with me? Just give me your opinion. Thank you!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this approach, and some built-in utilities use this pattern (`StringBuilder`, for instance).  Personally I don't like it, but that's just me.  If it works for you, then go for it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4899756/240633

Comment: You would have to return a reference if you want the different setters to modify the same object, or else store the object somewhere at the end of the chain of setters.

Answer (score 5):

This is generally used to create a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) and can be implemented in any language.

- Pros: can improve readability and allows for more concise code.
- Cons: debugging may be harder as breakpoints are usually line-based.

Answer (score 4):

This is typically called as **Method Chaining** in C++.
Using Method Chaining is more a question of choice.

The most common use of method chaining is in the iostream library.
E.g., `cout << x << y` works because `cout << x` is a function that returns `cout`.

Method chaning is typically used in **[Named Parameter Idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.20)**.

Answer (score 0):

Method chaining works fine in C++, and doing it is no problem at all.

Using getters/setters (aka accessors and mutators) enough to care about chaining them hints that your code has [design problems](http://www.idinews.com/quasiClass.pdf) though.